# how to apply patch in mercurial and show diff tool if failed apply

Tags: python, mercurial, patch

I want apply patch in Mercurial:

```
hg import patch_name.patch
```

But if I get the error `abort: patch failed to apply`, Mercurial creates `*.rej` files.

Is there a way show kdiff or vim-diif to correcting conflict.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do this.  The recommended approach is to open the file and the .rej file and manually merge in the rejected hunks.

Answer (score 2):

I would bet that hg returns an error code. Perhaps you can wrap `hg import` in a shell script that catches the error code returned and does what you want if there was an error? Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# run the script by typing `hgimp patch_name.patch`
# $1 below will contain patch_name.patch
hg import $1

# if the return code is not equal to 0, run vimdiff or whatever
if [ ! "$?" -eq '0' ]; then
    # run your diff/cleanup commands here
fi
```